# How can i flip images vertically and Horizontally at a time in react native.

Tags: image, react-native, flip

i am able to flip the image either vertically or horizontally
but i want both the actions at once.Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Animated from react-native. Code would be something like following.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Animated } from 'react-native';

export default class AppProject extends Component 
  {

```
constructor(){

  super();


}

flip_Card_Animation=()=> {

    Animated.spring(this.animatedValue,{
      toValue: 0,
      tension: 10,
      friction: 8,
    }).start();
}

render() {

  this.SetInterpolate = this.animatedValue.interpolate({

    inputRange: [0, 180],

    outputRange: ['180deg', '360deg']

  })

  const Rotate_Y_AnimatedStyle = {

    transform: [

      { rotateY: this.SetInterpolate }

    ]

  }

  return (

    <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Animated.Image source={{uri : 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/motorcycle.jpg'}} 
        style={[Rotate_Y_AnimatedStyle, styles.imageViewStyle]}>

        </Animated.Image>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.TouchableOpacity_button} onPress={this.flip_Card_Animation} >

          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Click Here Flip </Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>

);
}
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: its possible to flip only vertical or horizontal view, but how can i flip both vertically and horizontally at a time by using two TouchableOpacity's .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by adding `transform: [ { scaleX: -1 },{ scaleY: -1 }]` in Image style.

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/3a27dc4d9b5ed67b4b773f049b5de2466101f3b7/e47c0/img/showcase/facebook.png'}}
  style={{ width: 100, height: 100, transform: [ { scaleX: -1 },{ scaleY: -1 }] }}/>
```